# How to use component in lazy loading and entryComponents in angular4

Tags: angular

I have component, page_and_modal, I want to use it as part of lazy loading module and in model.

However, when I put PageAndModalCompoent in entryComponents, it doesn't work, it throws following error

> page_and_modal is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MainModule
>   and pageModule! Please consider moving PageAndModalCompoent to a
>   higher module that imports MainModule and pageModule.

Is any one knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are tying to include your component in two module. first one app module and another lazy module. thats the problem.

pls visit this website for example lazy loading

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html